# Calculation of sum of hours in 24h format with incorrect C#

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a mistake in calculating the hours. The values you see below are taken from a database and my task with C # is to do the sum of the hours.

I list the problems below:

1) Total wrong hours,

2) As you can see in the data grid view there is a time with 9.7 hours but it is impossible that there are 70 minutes in an hour! I place below the C # code and the relative data grid view, can you help me to solve it?

**DataGridView Value:**

```
24-07-2018  9:7     08:30
25-07-2018  0:0     08:30 
26-07-2018  9:42    08:30

Final sum-> 18:49    1:30
```

**C# Code:**

```
     private void buttonCarica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       dataGridViewPrincipale.Hide();
       dataGridViewSecondario.Hide();
       resetDataGrid();
       string StartDate = dateTimePickerInizio.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
       string EndData = dateTimePickerFine.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
       Utente utemp = new Utente(comboBoxUtenti.Text);
       timemanager tm = new timemanager(utemp);
       PeopleController r = new PeopleController(utemp);
       DataTable dt = tm.CaricaDataeTotaleHour(StartDate, EndData);

       if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
       {
         reset();
         MessageBox.Show("\n ATTENZIONE:  " + comboBoxUtenti.Text + " in questo range di tempo non ha effettuato marcature");
       }
       else
       {
         labelTotaleHourWork.Show();
         labelTotaleHourWorkMod.Show();
         labelTotaleHourtimemanagerMod.Show();
         labelTotaletimemanager.Show();
         dataGridViewPrincipale.Show();
         TimeSpan tempoSpanTotaleHourWork = TimeSpan.Zero;

         foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
         {
           String TotaleHourWork = r.CaricaHourGiornaliere(dr["Data"].ToString());
           if (TotaleHour.Equals("0") == false)
           {
             TotaleHourWork = TotaleHourWork.Replace(",", ":");
             tempoSpanTotaleHourWork = SommaHour(TotaleHourWork, tempoSpanTotaleHourWork);
           }

           if (tempoSpanTotaleHourWork == TimeSpan.Zero)
           {
             TotaleHourWork = "0";
           }

           String[] row = { dr["Data"].ToString(), "" + tm.ConteggioHourGiornaliere(dr["Data"].ToString()), "" + TotaleHourWork };
           dataGridViewPrincipale.Rows.Add(row);
         }

         labelTotaleHourtimemanagerMod.Text = "" + tm.GetTotaleHourRange();
         labelTotaleHourWorkMod.Text = "" + CheckValue.ConversioneTimeSpantoString(tempoSpanTotaleHourWork);
         }
       }

private TimeSpan SommaHour(String t1, TimeSpan t2)
{
  t1= TotaleOreCantiere.ToString().Replace(",", ":");
  tempoSpanTotaleOreCantiere = tempoSpanTotaleOreCantiere + TimeSpan.Parse(t2);
  return tempoSpanTotaleOreCantiere;
}
```

**Function CaricaHourGiornaliere  :**

```
public String CaricaHourGiornaliere(String Data)
{
  String ret = "0";
  DataTable dt = RisorseUmaneModel.CaricaHourGiornaliere(Data);

  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  {
    ret = dr["Ore"].ToString();
  }

  return ret;
}
```

--RisorseUmaneModel--

```
public static DataTable CaricaHourGiornaliere ( String Data)
{
  String Query = " SET LANGUAGE 'Italian' SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), People.Data, 105) as DataIns,''+Utente.Nome+' '+Utente.Cognome as Risorsa,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, People.Data) as Giorno,Cliente.RagioneSociale,Working.NomeWorking,convert(varchar(5), Cast(convert(varchar(5), (OreFine - OreInizio), 108) as datetime) - CAST(REPLACE(Pausa, '.', ':') as datetime), 108) as Ore FROM People inner join Working on Working.IdWorking = People.IdWorking inner join Cliente on Working.IdCliente = Cliente.IdCliente inner join Utente on Utente.IdUtente=People.IdUtente  where People.IdUtente = @IdUtente and(People.Data between @Start and @End) order by CONVERT(DateTime, People.Data,101)  asc";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn, tran);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUtente", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Data;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Data;
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  da.Fill(dt);

  return dt
}
```

**Function CheckValue.ConversioneTimeSpantoString :**

```
public static String ConversioneTimeSpantoString(TimeSpan tm)
{
      return "" + tm.Hours.ToString().Replace("-", "").ToString() + ":" + tm.Minutes.ToString().Replace("-", "").ToString();
}
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko 
the result as you say it should be 25:30 but it comes 1:30 but I can not understand why

Comment: Try providing formats explisitly, e.g. instead of `String TotaleHourWork = r.CaricaHourGiornaliere(dr["Data"].ToString())` put `String TotaleHourWork = r.CaricaHourGiornaliere(dr["Data"].ToString("d\\.hh\\:mm\\:ss"))` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Comment: @DmitryBychenko now i try

Comment: @DmitryBychenko 
if I use your code on toString it gives me an error before compiling and it says that No overload method for ToString take1 arguments

Comment: `what is dr["Data"]` type? I.e. what is `dr["Data"].GetType()` result?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko  dr["Data"]  is a string that is taken from the database, waiting for the code that picks up the value from the db

Comment: Show us what's inside :  CheckValue.ConversioneTimeSpantoString please

Comment: @Jimbot i add it

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `public static String ConversioneTimeSpantoString(TimeSpan tm)`

Change

```
tm.Hours //-> the remining hours in this timespan (minus days)
```

To

```
tm.TotalHours //-> the sum of all hours in this timespan (included days, months, years)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the hours are no longer calculated correctly

Answer (score 0):

`TotaleHourWork.Replace(",", ":");`

"9:7" means 9 hours, 7 minutes.
"9,7" probably means 9,7 hours, which is 9 hours and 42 minutes.

So whatever you think this does, it does not. It's just corrupting most of your data.

Stop doing string replacements, take your date, parse it into TimeSpans properly and then calculate your numbers using those.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: it is possible to convert (7) into 42 minutes @nvoigt

Comment: I don't know... why would you want to? You could do `TimeSpan.FromHours(0.7)` but if you need to do that you should take a minute and make sure you are doing the right thing.

Comment: I can not change the query is already used for other things, so I have to try to understand the minutes well

Comment: I have really no idea why it's so complicated. "9:7" seems like a fine data point. Parse it into a TimeSpan, add them all up, done. [I just don't understand your logic because all your variable names are gibberish to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/)